# LDA topic model plotting by year

Tags: r, topic-modeling

I'm trying to plot tweet topics by year from this file

https://www.mediafire.com/file/64lzbt46v01jbe1/cleaned.xlsx/file

works fine to get the topics, but when I try to plot them by year I have a dimensions problem:

```
library(readxl)
library(tm)
tweets <- read_xlsx("C:/cleaned.xlsx")

mytextdata <- tweets$textdata

# Convert to tm corpus and use its API 
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(mytextdata))  # Create corpus object

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
ui = unique(dtm$i)
dtm.new = dtm[ui,]

k <- 7
ldaTopics <- LDA(dtm.new, method = "Gibbs", control=list(alpha = 0.1, seed = 77), k = k)
tmResult <- posterior(ldaTopics)
theta <- tmResult$topics
dim(theta)
```

dim(theta)=4857 and I have 4876 dates in my cleaned.xls file and I need them to be the same to run this aggregate function

```
topic_proportion_per_decade <- aggregate(theta, by = list(decade = textdata$decade), mean)
```

from here

https://tm4ss.github.io/docs/Tutorial_6_Topic_Models.html

I think that the problem is that the cleaned.xls file is not clean enough and that's why theta misses some rows..
But in fact I really don't know why theta misses some rows..
 I also don't know how to clean the file better if that was the problem, the file looks good to me, there are some rows that are only numbers or non-english words but I prefer to keep them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ui = unique(dtm$i)` removes several documents (I don't know why you do this, so I won't comment on that part). So your theta doesn't have the same number of rows as the data. We can solve this by only keeping the rows which are still in theta:

```
library("dplyr")
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")
tweets_clean <- tweets %>% 
  mutate(id = rownames(.)) %>% 
  filter(id %in% rownames(theta)) %>% # keep only rows still in theta
  cbind(theta) %>% # now we can attach the topics to the data.frame
  mutate(year = format(date, "%Y")) # make year variable
```

I then used `dplyr` functions to make the aggregation, since I think it makes for easier to read code:

```
tweets_clean_yearly <- tweets_clean %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(as.character(1:7)), funs(mean)) %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "year")
```

Then we can plot this:

```
ggplot(tweets_clean_yearly, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  ylab("proportion")
```

[image: plot]

**Note**: I tested if theta and tweets had really the same documents with:

```
tweets_clean <- tweets %>% 
  mutate(id = rownames(.)) %>% 
  filter(id %in% rownames(theta))

all.equal(tweets_clean$id, rownames(theta))
```

Comment: BTW (and this is a very opinionated comment) I think you should look into the quanteda package or tidytext. I believe both are superior to tm nowadays.